# Can't get GPS to automatically work after reboot

Tags: raspbian, gps

I have GPSd installed, but I can't get it to work after reboot.

After reboot, when I run `cgps -s` I just get `cgps: GPS timeout`. However, if I run: `sudo killall gpsd; sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock` then `cgps` works just fine.

After running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd`, here's my `/etc/default/gpsd` file:

```
# Default settings for gpsd.
# Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd' to
# change the options.
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
USBAUTO="true"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

What can I do to get it working after reboot? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution from here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=53644

The TL;DR is that you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd` and disable USB AutoLoad

My steps:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd`
2. Start gpsd automatically? `Yes`
3. Should gpsd handle attached USB GPS receivers automatically? `No`
4. Device the GPS receiver is attached to: `/dev/gps0` (check that on your machine to match)
5. Options to gpsd: `-n`
6. gpsd control socket path: `/var/run/gpsd.sock`

So the correct `/etc/default/gpsd` would be:

```
# Default settings for gpsd.
# Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd' to
# change the options.
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"
DEVICES="/dev/gps0"
USBAUTO="false"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with this today with Raspbian Jesse, which may help some people. Solution for my set up to enable automatic start of GPS on bootup for NAVIT, was as follows:

First set the following with `sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd`:

```
START_DAEMON="true"
# Use USB hotplugging to add new USB devices automatically to the daemon
USBAUTO="true"
# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.
# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group dialout.
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_SOCKET=”/var/run/gpsd.sock”
```

I had previously worked through the following:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-hat-for-raspberry-pi/use-gpsd

So I simply did the following to re-enable the psd systemd service:

```
sudo systemctl enable gpsd.socket
sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and like @Dan Mandle, I found the answer at the same URI [https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=53644](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=5364)

However, the configuration file was different as submitted by amrbekhit.  The`/etc/default/gpsd` file that worked for me was the following:

```
# Default settings for gpsd.
# Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd' to
# change the options.
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
DEVICES=""
USBAUTO="true"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on Raspbian Lite of July 2017, release date 2017-07-05, with a ublox based USB GPS from Navilock.

The `/etc/default/gpsd` file that worked for me was the following:

```
START_DAEMON="true"
USBAUTO="true"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyACM0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

But `systemctl enable gpsd.service` does not create the correct symlink, instead it modifies the old sysvinit with update-rc.d.  I don't know why systemctl chooses to go for sysvinit here, but it took me a couple of hours figuring that out. With some more searching I found [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=53644#p1048128) from federico.human referring to this [original guide](http://www.satsignal.eu/ntp/Raspberry-Pi-quickstart.html) who also come to this solution:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/
```

After a reboot gpsd is up an running, check with `ps -aux | grep gpsd`

Answer (score 0):

I had problems for sometime to trying to get cgps to run on the terminal, sometimes it worked, most times it never worked correctly, what I had used to edit the file and save was..

```
sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
```

But when I typed in the following code at the terminal. 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gpsd

I received "Creating/updating gpsd user account..."    I then rebooted and it all Worked when I ran `cgps` or `gpsmon`.

Thank you Dan Mandel :)

Since my GPS is not a USB device, my code in the gpsd file: `etc/default/gpsd`

was only

```
START_DAEMON="true"
DEVICES="/dev/serial0"
```